# Integral estimation verification

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification

We have that $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ is a measurable space and that  $f\in L^{1}(\mu)$ .

and let $A\in\mathcal{A}$  and we want to make some estimations for the following intergral

$$\int_{A}\left | f \right |d\mu$$

Is it correct to assume that , because  ($f\in L^{1}(\mu)$ $\Rightarrow$ $f$ is finite a.e and because $\left | f \right |\geq 0$) $\Rightarrow$ $\left | f \right |$ will have max , lets call it $M$.

Then $\int_{A}\left | f \right |d\mu\leq M\mu(A)$ ??

Comment: Finite a.e. means that the set $\{x:\ |f(x)|=\infty\}$ has measure zero. But it doesn't mean bounded, or even essentially bounded. Take any unbounded integrable function, like $1/\sqrt{x}$ on $[0,1]$.

Comment: I see , but how we are supposed to bound this intergral ?? I thought beucase $f$ is intergrable it had to be bouned .

Comment: I don't know what is your ultimate purpose for a bound of the integral. If there is any, you better ask that directly. In principle $\int_A|f|\leq \int_X|f|=\|f\|_1$ is a bound.